# Code for for deleting names with the Workbook scope deletes Worksheet names instead

Tags: excel, vba

I need to distribute numerous single forms that contain just one worksheet with data. In the source project the empty model form is copied and renamed. This form is filled with data, then moved out of the source project and saved under a new name. When opening the new file it asks to solve lost links. In the file are names referring to the scope of the original source project. I want to delete those names and not the names of the new sheet.

6 names in Names manager: 3 names in scope Single form (new sheet) and 3 names in scope Workbook (werkmap)
[image]

I created this code

```
Sub DeleteSheetNames()
    Dim n As Name
    Sheets("Single form").Select
    For Each nmm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If nm.Name Like "*!*" Then
            nm.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It does not delete any name.

I tried this code:

```
Sub DeleteWorkbookScopedNamedRanges()
Dim nm As Name
    '   Loop through each named Range
    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        '   Is Name scoped at the Workbook level?
        If TypeOf nm.Parent Is Workbook Then
            nm.Delete
        End If
    Next nm
End Sub
```

It deleted the wrong set of names: the names with the worksheet scope.

Wrong set of names remain
[image]

The question is: how do I delete the names with the scope referring to the unwanted source workbook names?

Getting back wit a solution due to the remark of user10186832 I changed the workflow.

Old workflow:
copy the source worksheet to a result sheet inside the same workbook.
edit it.
move it and save as new workbook.
*This saves names in two scopes.*

New workflow:
copy the source worksheet to a new result sheet outside workbook.
edit it.
save as new workbook.
*This saves names in one scope only.*

It still leaves the question on how to delete names with a certain scope unanwere for but I can continue my project.

Comment: As I understand it the names you want to delete are not in the workbook you are running the code on. The names are linked to the parent workbook. You need to break the links.